# How can I return a left value in Python functions?

Tags: python, c, function, python-2.7

As you know, in C/C++, I can return a pointer in a function, and use it as left value as below:

```
typedef char* (*func)(char *); 

char* foo(char *a) {
  return &a[0];
}

char* foo2(char *a) {
  return &a[1];
}

void goo(func f, char* a) {
  f(a)[0] = 10; 
}

int main(void) {
  char a[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
  goo(foo, a); 
}
```

How can I make it in Python(return a left value in a Python function)?

```
def foo(a):
    return a

def foo2(a):
    return a[0, :]

import numpy as np
p = np.random.rand(5, 2)

foo(p)[0,:] = [1,2] # ok
foo2(p) = [1, 2] # error
print p
```

why ok and error in my code??

Comment: Python strings are not mutable; you can return *mutable* objects from a function and use them as assignment targets just fine (if `f` returns a `list`, then `f()[0] = 1` will assign `1` to the first element of that returned list). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a mutable object, such as a one-element list:

```
a = [None]

def foo():
    return a

foo()[0] = "hello"

print(a)  # prints "hello"
```

However, this is not necessarily idiomatic Python: Python functions usually pass objects around instead of memory buffers, so there might be a better way to solve your actual problem. It also can't directly emulate your `foo` and `foo2` functions. There are ways to do that as well, but they tend to be even uglier than the previous code snippet.